# how to do python parallel processing by Spyder

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ide, spyder

I try to do parallel processing in python, my IDE was Spyder. I could not! I tried the same codes in other IDEs like PyCharm and it worked. How can I fix the Spyder IDE to do it for me? I tried the official Python documentation below, all of them give errors in Spyder IDE!!
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_context

Comment: what means `I could not!` ? Did you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: and where is your code ?

Answer (score -1):

I used all the codes in python documentation for parallel processing. The link is:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_context
it seems Spyder has issues, instead, I used PyCharm, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: There are no error reports in your question and this is not an answer to it.